# Finitely generated field is a finite field

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

A ring $R$ is said to be finitely generated if there exists a finite subset $A$ of $R$ such that for all rings $R'\subset R$ with $A\subset R'$ we have $R'=R$. ($A$ is called the generating set of $R$)

Following is the statement that I want to prove:

> If $F$ is a field which is finitely generated as a ring, then $F$ is a
>   finite field.

This is supposed to follow as a corollary to the general Nullstellensatz (Eisenbud, Theorem 4.19)

**Theorem:** *Let $R$ be a Jacobson ring. If $S$ is a finitely generated $R$-algebra with the ring homomorphism $\varphi: R\to S$, then $S$ is a Jacobson ring. Further, if $J\subset S$ is a maximal ideal, then $I = \varphi^{-1}(J)$ is a maximal ideal of $R$, and $S/J$ is a finite field extension of $R/I$.*

If $F$ is a field of characteristic $p$ then the result follows by taking $R=\mathbb{F}_p$ and $S=F$ in the above theorem. **But, how to show that $F$ can't be of characteristic $0$?**

Comment: Replaced Jacobian with Jacobson.

Comment: @RaviFernando Funny how the accepted answer to the duplicate is a textbook example of "link only" answer.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier The link at this answer points to a post at this site, which Pierre-Yves Gaillard had written before for this site. Why should he not cite this? "Link only" mostly refers to some document outside of MSE, which may not stay there.